# Firefox: Selected radio button changes automatically when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery, firefox, radio-button

I have three radio buttons, that first is selected (with checked="checked"). But when I refresh the page the selected input automatically toggles between first and second input!

That's strange! With firebug, I can see that only the first input has checked="checked" attribute, but in rendered page the second is selected!

Any opinion?!

[Note: JQuery is loaded on page, but I think it's not related to jQuery)

Comment: Well, radio button state isn't automatically preserved across post-backs, so you'll have to do some extra work on the server to make it happen. You'll have to post some actual code for anyone to say anything useful though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You just refresh or click on F5 on Page, Last Selected Item saved, but if you Press Ctrl + F5 ( Hard Refresh ), Item's reset to default .

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is a known bug. [Bug 394782](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=394782)

The workaround for this issue is to add autocomplete="off" in the form tag

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Worth noting that it also appears to work if you put `autocomplete="off"` in each of the individual radio button tags.

Comment: @seanlinmt, thank you. I looked everywhere for why the hell this was happening and this finally fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can add 'document.forms[0].reset()' in script tags at the end of the doc, and this does correctly show the 'CHECKED' values even though the original reload did not.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338593

However still finding the similar issue on IE. Any fixes for IE?